# Does hitting a shugenja while casting disrupt the spell?

Tags: spells, l5r, l5r-2e

In L5R 2nd ed, if a shugenja has successfully cast a spell with a casting time greater than one turn, does she have to roll some kind of "concentration check" if she is hit during a casting turn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 4th Edition, under Spell Casting Rolls & Target Numbers, there is text devoted to interruptions.

> A shugenja who is interrupted must succeed at a Willpower Trait Roll (TN 10) to overcome distraction. If the shugenja suffers damage, the TN for the Willpower roll is 5 plus the amount of damage suffered. A spell that is disrupted in this manner cannot be completed, but the shugenja does not lose the spell slot.

4th Edition also allows you to reduce the casting time by Raising once per Complex Action of reduction (down to one). A Mastery Level 3 spell can be cast in 1 Complex Action by Raising twice.

Other editions may have similar rules. If not, you can probably backport the rules above into your game.